# Delete shapes in range does not work with drop down cells

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown, shapes

I have VBA code to delete shapes in range and everything is working perfectly until I run vba while any drop down cell is selected, at this stage vba still runs through all shapes in worksheet and then it looks like if it find one extra and fails at part:

```
If Application.Intersect(wsA.Range("b11:g32"), Range(sh.TopLeftCell, sh.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing Then
```

Why is that and how i can solve it? I tried at the start of vba to specify selection of specific cell without dropdown but it doesn't help

Comment: I did, this vba runs on button click and first thing is to select range where is no dropdown but it doesn't help

Comment: The line of code your second `Range` is not necessarily in the same worksheet as your first one `wsA.Range`. Make sure to specify `wsA` for both otherwise you cannot `Intersect` if they are in differend worksheets. Never leave any `Range` without specifying a sheet. • If that does not solve the issue, then [edit] your question and add a [mcve] that reproduces the issue properly.

Comment: Loop through the `DrawingObjects` collection, not the `Shapes` collection, and it won't include data validation dropdowns.

Comment: everything is in the same worksheet, I have specified worksheet for second 'If Application.Intersect(wsA.Range("b11:g32"), wsA.Range(sh.TopLeftCell, sh.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing Then'

Comment: *"everything is in the same worksheet"* still needs all ranges to be specified to that one worksheet. • Well then the problem is not in the code you show. Unless you provide a proper [mcve] as I requested, no one can help you.

Comment: If you have a DV dropdown, any attempt to refer to its `TopLeftCell` or `BottomRightCell` properties (and many others) will cause a run-time error. Use the `DrawingObjects` collection or an error handler.